# Why can't I get topological sort over the control-flow graph (CFG)?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api, control-flow-graph

Final goal: Trying to generate CFG related information(such as topological sort) using LLVM.

Status: I'm pretty new to LLVM and kind of lost - any kind of information or blogs to help me get started towards my final goal is great!

My Question: After reading Eli's code and [blog post](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples/blob/master/src_llvm/bb_toposort_sccs.cpp), I get the .ll file first and run the code but I got no result.

Here is the .ll file example:

```
; ModuleID = 'CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83a.cpp'
source_filename = "CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83a.cpp"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

%"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_bad" = type { i8* }
%"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_goodG2B" = type { i8* }

; Function Attrs: noinline optnone uwtable
define void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_833badEv() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i8*, align 8
  %2 = alloca [100 x i8], align 16
  %3 = alloca %"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_bad", align 8
  %4 = bitcast [100 x i8]* %2 to i8*
  call void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i64(i8* %4, i8 0, i64 100, i32 16, i1 false)
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds [100 x i8], [100 x i8]* %2, i32 0, i32 0
  store i8* %5, i8** %1, align 8
  %6 = load i8*, i8** %1, align 8
  call void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_8369CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_badC1EPc(%"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_bad"* %3, i8* %6)
  call void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_8369CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_badD1Ev(%"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_bad"* %3) #4
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: argmemonly nounwind
declare void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i64(i8* nocapture writeonly, i8, i64, i32, i1) #1

declare void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_8369CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_badC1EPc(%"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_bad"*, i8*) unnamed_addr #2

; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_8369CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_badD1Ev(%"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_bad"*) unnamed_addr #3

; Function Attrs: noinline optnone uwtable
define void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_834goodEv() #0 {
  call void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83L7goodG2BEv()
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: noinline optnone uwtable
define internal void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83L7goodG2BEv() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i8*, align 8
  %2 = alloca [100 x i8], align 16
  %3 = alloca %"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_goodG2B", align 8
  %4 = bitcast [100 x i8]* %2 to i8*
  call void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i64(i8* %4, i8 0, i64 100, i32 16, i1 false)
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds [100 x i8], [100 x i8]* %2, i32 0, i32 0
  store i8* %5, i8** %1, align 8
  %6 = load i8*, i8** %1, align 8
  call void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_8373CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_goodG2BC1EPc(%"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_goodG2B"* %3, i8* %6)
  call void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_8373CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_goodG2BD1Ev(%"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_goodG2B"* %3) #4
  ret void
}

declare void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_8373CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_goodG2BC1EPc(%"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_goodG2B"*, i8*) unnamed_addr #2

; Function Attrs: nounwind
declare void @_ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_8373CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_goodG2BD1Ev(%"class.CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83::CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83_goodG2B"*) unnamed_addr #3

attributes #0 = { noinline optnone uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #1 = { argmemonly nounwind }
attributes #2 = { "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #3 = { nounwind "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #4 = { nounwind }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}
!llvm.ident = !{!1}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"wchar_size", i32 4}
!1 = !{!"clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final 375507)"}
```

and here is the .cpp file which generate sort information:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// bb_toposort_sccs LLVM sample. Demonstrates:
//
// * How to implement DFS & topological sort over the control-flow graph (CFG)
//   of a function.
// * How to use po_iterator for post-order iteration over basic blocks.
// * How to use scc_iterator for post-order iteration over strongly-connected
//   components in the graph of basic blocks.
//
// Eli Bendersky (eliben@gmail.com)
// This code is in the public domain
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/PostOrderIterator.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/SCCIterator.h"
#include "llvm/IR/CFG.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DataLayout.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instruction.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h"
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace llvm;

// Runs a topological sort on the basic blocks of the given function. Uses
// the simple recursive DFS from "Introduction to algorithms", with 3-coloring
// of vertices. The coloring enables detecting cycles in the graph with a simple
// test.
class TopoSorter {
public:
  void runToposort(const Function &F) {
    outs() << "Topological sort of " << F.getName() << ":\n";
    // Initialize the color map by marking all the vertices white.
    for (Function::const_iterator I = F.begin(), IE = F.end(); I != IE; ++I) {
      ColorMap[&*I] = TopoSorter::WHITE;
    }

    // The BB graph has a single entry vertex from which the other BBs should
    // be discoverable - the function entry block.
    bool success = recursiveDFSToposort(&F.getEntryBlock());
    if (success) {
      // Now we have all the BBs inside SortedBBs in reverse topological order.
      for (BBVector::const_reverse_iterator RI = SortedBBs.rbegin(),
                                            RE = SortedBBs.rend();
           RI != RE; ++RI) {
        outs() << "  " << (*RI)->getName() << "\n";
      }
    } else {
      outs() << "  Sorting failed\n";
    }
  }

private:
  enum Color { WHITE, GREY, BLACK };
  // Color marks per vertex (BB).
  typedef DenseMap<const BasicBlock *, Color> BBColorMap;
  // Collects vertices (BBs) in "finish" order. The first finished vertex is
  // first, and so on.
  typedef SmallVector<const BasicBlock *, 32> BBVector;
  BBColorMap ColorMap;
  BBVector SortedBBs;

  // Helper function to recursively run topological sort from a given BB.
  // Returns true if the sort succeeded and false otherwise; topological sort
  // may fail if, for example, the graph is not a DAG (detected a cycle).
  bool recursiveDFSToposort(const BasicBlock *BB) {
    ColorMap[BB] = TopoSorter::GREY;
    // For demonstration, using the lowest-level APIs here. A BB's successors
    // are determined by looking at its terminator instruction.
    const TerminatorInst *TInst = BB->getTerminator();
    for (unsigned I = 0, NSucc = TInst->getNumSuccessors(); I < NSucc; ++I) {
      BasicBlock *Succ = TInst->getSuccessor(I);
      Color SuccColor = ColorMap[Succ];
      if (SuccColor == TopoSorter::WHITE) {
        if (!recursiveDFSToposort(Succ))
          return false;
      } else if (SuccColor == TopoSorter::GREY) {
        // This detects a cycle because grey vertices are all ancestors of the
        // currently explored vertex (in other words, they're "on the stack").
        outs() << "  Detected cycle: edge from " << BB->getName() << " to "
               << Succ->getName() << "\n";
        return false;
      }
    }
    // This BB is finished (fully explored), so we can add it to the vector.
    ColorMap[BB] = TopoSorter::BLACK;
    SortedBBs.push_back(BB);
    return true;
  }
};

class AnalyzeBBGraph : public FunctionPass {
public:
  AnalyzeBBGraph(const std::string &AnalysisKind)
      : FunctionPass(ID), AnalysisKind(AnalysisKind) {}

  virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
    if (AnalysisKind == "-topo") {
      TopoSorter TS;
      TS.runToposort(F);
    } else if (AnalysisKind == "-po") {
      // Use LLVM's post-order iterator to produce a reverse topological sort.
      // Note that this doesn't detect cycles so if the graph is not a DAG, the
      // result is not a true topological sort.
      outs() << "Basic blocks of " << F.getName() << " in post-order:\n";
      for (po_iterator<BasicBlock *> I = po_begin(&F.getEntryBlock()),
                                     IE = po_end(&F.getEntryBlock());
           I != IE; ++I) {
        outs() << "  " << (*I)->getName() << "\n";
      }
    } else if (AnalysisKind == "-scc") {
      // Use LLVM's Strongly Connected Components (SCCs) iterator to produce
      // a reverse topological sort of SCCs.
      outs() << "SCCs for " << F.getName() << " in post-order:\n";
      for (scc_iterator<Function *> I = scc_begin(&F), IE = scc_end(&F);
           I != IE; ++I) {
        // Obtain the vector of BBs in this SCC and print it out.
        const std::vector<BasicBlock *> &SCCBBs = *I;
        outs() << "  SCC: ";
        for (std::vector<BasicBlock *>::const_iterator BBI = SCCBBs.begin(),
                                                       BBIE = SCCBBs.end();
             BBI != BBIE; ++BBI) {
          outs() << (*BBI)->getName() << "  ";
        }
        outs() << "\n";
      }
    } else {
      outs() << "Unknown analysis kind: " << AnalysisKind << "\n";
    }
    return false;
  }

  // The address of this member is used to uniquely identify the class. This is
  // used by LLVM's own RTTI mechanism.
  static char ID;

private:
  std::string AnalysisKind;
};

char AnalyzeBBGraph::ID = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc < 3) {
    // Using very basic command-line argument parsing here...
    errs() << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " -[topo|po|scc] <IR file>\n";
    return 1;
  }

  // Parse the input LLVM IR file into a module.
  SMDiagnostic Err;
  LLVMContext Context;
  std::unique_ptr<Module> Mod(parseIRFile(argv[2], Err, Context));
  if (!Mod) {
    Err.print(argv[0], errs());
    return 1;
  }

  // Create a pass manager and fill it with the passes we want to run.
  legacy::PassManager PM;
  PM.add(new AnalyzeBBGraph(std::string(argv[1])));
  PM.run(*Mod);

  return 0;
}
```

here is my result looks like when I try to get topo sort:

```
Topological sort of _ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_833badEv:

Topological sort of _ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_834goodEv:

Topological sort of _ZN65CWE15_External_Control_of_System_or_Configuration_Setting__w32_83L7goodG2BEv:
```

I tried something else and I found out all the "getName()" print is nothing,
Is there something wrong with my code or somrthing wrong with my llvm IR ?

```
for(BasicBlock &BB : F){
      outs() << "BB:" <<BB.getName() <<" has" <<BB.size() <<"instructions.\n"; 
      for(Instruction &I : BB){
        outs() << "details: "<<I <<"name: "<<I.getName() <<"\n";
        for(Use &U : I.operands()){
           Value *v = U.get();
           outs() <<"value:"<< v<<"name:" << v->getName() <<"\n";
        }
      }

    }
```

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to run the [instruction namer](https://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#instnamer-assign-names-to-anonymous-instructions) pass after you obtain your IR (the .ll file) in order to assign names to the basic blocks and the registers, because currently, they do not have any names apart from their numeric assignment (e.g. `%1`, etc). You can run this with:

```
opt -instnamer foo.bc -o foo-named.bc
```

The 3 functions definitions have only one basic block in them, so you are not going to get anything interesting, but it is a good start.

Another point that you might want to address now before moving on, is the optimization level. All your functions are annotated with `optnone` that will disable any kind of optimization from other LLVM passes. A more flexible way to get unoptimized IR, but one that will allow further optimizations to take effect on it is to extracted using:

```
clang -emit-llvm -O1 -Xclang -disable-llvm-passes foo.c
```